# Back-end Service

Tags: android, laravel, playframework

I am building a simple taxi booking application. I am building a native android application. But I am confused in choosing the frameworks in the back-end. Can you guys please suggest me whether to use Laravel or Play framework as a back-end.

Any suggestions or help in choosing the back-end is needed.

Comment: I don't think this kind of questions can be answered here. Either way, choose whatever feels better for you or have more experience. If you are also building the Android app you can take advantage of that knowledge to use it in Play, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an Android developer, I suggest you to use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) from Google, especially if your making a `small` app. Firebase is very simple to use and reliable!

You don't need to care about how many users you have: 100 users or 10K users, Firebase handles it!

You have a Realtime Database (you don't need to make request to the database to see if any changes... It uses callbacks so you're automatically notified when something happens)

All the authentication part is also handled, don't need to care about accounts or security!

To be honest I started using Firebase 2 days ago, so I can't tell you much more, but I tested some features and I'm really impressed of the good work they done!

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hey Omar, thank you for the suggestion. But i want to use either laravel or play. Can you please suggest me which among these is the better one.

Comment: I tried once Laravel, and it looked pretty fusy... It's all I can tell you sorry..